# Asp.net application life cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

This question might sound silly but I never got a clear answer anywhere. I am trying to figure out how asp.net application actually works, in windows app (.net) when an application is deployed on one or more PC then user can click open the app and an instance of that application is created, if user again opens the app then another instance is created (opening multiple excel files could be an example). But on web, since the application is deployed on web server and there could be multiple  user requesting same app so is there a mechanism to create an instance of asp.net web app for every unique browser request? In another words if A and B are two users and access same app then does two instance (inst A , inst B) are created on web server to process the request?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx Simply speaking, your web app becomes `HttpApplication` derived objects (pipelines) running in `w3wp.exe`, and incoming requests would be processed by them. The scheduling is complex, and requests from different users can come to the same pipeline.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because. Just be-cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webapplication itself has one instance. Each request is handled by different threads. Each request goes through application pipeline (different for old ASP.NET, different for ASP.NET Core )which in most common scenario creates new instance of class responsible for handling request (usually controller). Rest is defined in scopes (so if some of your classes are singletons or limited instances or you use IoC containers with defined scopes), then they can share instances between different requests.

Basically what you don't see is a main loop function provided by framework, which handles all requests, creates classes instances and passes control to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net along with the web server and OS use *threads* to handle each request. Threads are much the same as processes you describe for separate instances of Excel. The threads allow each user session to be handled independently by the web server.

Comment: Thanks for responding, lets suppose we are building an application where user can upload a text file for processing and after processing a result will be shown and uploaded file will be deleted from folder, so to do that we create a folder 'usertextdata' in our project folder, now user A uploads a text file "Demo.txt" and at same time user B also uploads the text file with same name "Demo.txt" but with different content. Now as per your comment I believe there will be two threads of same app for each user to distinguish their data and the results will be different for each user.

Comment: Persistence is only one, the file saved by the first request is going to be overwritten by the last request.

Comment: @abhishek-anand what you are describing is a race condition. It's when two threads compete for the same resource. With the text file, the application would need to take steps to prevent this collision, such as giving each file a unique name.